# How to handover a .pdf or .png object using R in Foundry Code Workbook?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have created formatted tables using R and the package **gt** in Code Workbook. I would like to save them as `.png` or `.pdf` files so they can be used in other Foundry applications. Currently, I can only save them as `.html` files.

An example of what my current code looks like:

```
table <- function(metrics_national) {

    library(tidyverse)
    library(webshot)
    library(gt)
    
    table <- metrics_national %>%
    gt()  %>%
    tab_header(title = "My table")
    
    output <- new.output()
    output_fs <- output$fileSystem()
    table %>% gtsave(filename = output_fs$get_path("table.html",'w'))
    return(table)
}
```

This runs and saves the `.html` file as expected but when I change the filename extension to `.png` or `.pdf` instead of `.html` it stops working.

Comment: What error are you facing when you change the filename extension?